# Make two ajax requests run asynchronously

Tags: javascript, jquery, asynchronous

I am trying to make two ajax requests run asynchronously one after the other. The first request pulls the value of a user code, which is to be displayed in a div and then sent in the next ajax request to pull certain details about the user. I tried something like this:

```
var uid = "";
var token = "";

$.ajax({
    async: true,
    type: "POST",
    url: "http://www.example.com/apis/login.php",
    data: JSON.stringify(inputs),
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data) {
        if(data.status == "success") {
            uid = data.uid;
            token = decodeURIComponent(data.token);
        }
        else{
            alert(data.message);
        }
    },
    error: function() {
        alert("could not connect to server");
    }
});

document.getElementById("user-id").innerHTML = uid;

$.ajax({
    async: true,
    type: "GET",
    url: "http://www.example.com/apis/services.php",
    headers: {
        "Auth-Token" : encodeURIComponent(token),
        "U-Id" : uid
    },
    success: function(data) {
        alert("connected to server");
    },
    error: function() {
        alert("could not connect to server");
    }
});
```

But this does not work as expected, adding "async: true" or not adding "async" at all both have the same effect. The network console shows that the second ajax request is made before acquiring the response of the first request and so the second request fails due to invalid headers, so does the text box update of user id.

I could make it work by adding all the subsequent code after the first ajax call inside the success function of the the first request, but this is very inconvenient as some more apis are to be called after this and this will lead to nested calls which I am not willing to use.

Is there any way of making this code run asynchronously?? Please let me know.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: AJAX stands for "Asynchronous javascript and xml", `aysnc: true` is default, you can nest the callbacks like you said, or you can chain together [Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)

Comment: You're completely misunderstanding the word "asynchronous".  You need to use callbacks or promises.

Comment: How can this be async when you need the token from the first call to make the 2nd call?

Comment: this can't be async! you don't have the "uid" untill the first ajax request is completed...

Comment: @Liam Well the second call is dependent of the first, but they can both be async, there's no relation. They can just not run in parallel.

Comment: Okay, so I confused synchronous and asynchronous. That is really embarassing.Setting, asynchronous to true, makes the calls asynchronous. I get it. But even if I set it to false, or don't set it at all, the requests do not occur synchronously. Any comment on why it works like this? That the only way to execute anything after making an ajax call has to be either defined inside the success function or called as a function from the success block?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need to do is to set function which will be called on the success of first ajax request.

```
var uid = "";
var token = "";

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "http://www.example.com/apis/login.php",
    data: JSON.stringify(inputs),
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data) {
        if(data.status == "success") {
            uid = data.uid;
            token = decodeURIComponent(data.token);
            successCallback();
        }
        else{
            alert(data.message);
        }
    },
    error: function() {
        alert("could not connect to server");
    }
});


function successCallback()
{
    document.getElementById("user-id").innerHTML = uid;
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "http://www.example.com/apis/services.php",
        headers: {
            "Auth-Token" : encodeURIComponent(token),
            "U-Id" : uid
        },
        success: function(data) {
            alert("connected to server");
        },
        error: function() {
            alert("could not connect to server");
        }
    }); 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

A simple way, without promises, is to start the second call after the first one completes, and pass it the token from the first call :

```
$.ajax({
    url: "http://www.example.com/apis/login.php",
    //...
    success: function (data) {
        uid = data.uid;
        document.getElementById("user-id").innerHTML = uid;
        makeSecondCall(data.token);
    }
});


function makeSecondCall(token) {
    $.ajax({
        //...
        headers: {
            "Auth-Token": token,
            "U-Id": uid
        }
    });
}
```